# Asymptotic normality of estimator of uniform's distribution parameter

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

We have $X_1, ..., X_n \sim U[0, \theta]$ and estimator $\phi^*(X_{[n]}) = X_{(n)}$. $X_{(n)}$ here stands for $\max_iX_i$.

I need to made this estimator **unbiased** and check if it is asymptotic normal.

Unbiasing is easy: we need to find expectation of $\phi$. So $\mathbb{E}\phi = \frac{n}{n+1}\theta$. Bias is $b(\phi^*, \theta) = \mathbb{E}X_{(n)} - \theta = -\frac{\theta}{n + 1}$. So, unbiased estimator is $\tilde{\phi^*}$ = $\frac{n+1}{n}X_{(n)}$.

And now I need to check whether this unbiased estimator is **asymptotic normal**, i.e. $\sqrt{n}(\frac{n+1}{n}X_{(n)} - \theta) \to \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2(\theta) )$. How can I do that? Do I need to use central limit theorem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given $X_i$ are iid, it would be easy enough to obtain the CDF of the standardized estimator (we assume it is $n^\alpha$-consistent):

$$P\left(n^\alpha \left(\frac{n+1}{n}X_{(n)}-\theta \right)\leq x\right)=P\left(X_{(n)}\leq \frac{n}{n+1}\left(\frac{x}{n^\alpha}+\theta\right)\right)\\
=\frac{1}{\theta^n}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\left(\frac{x}{n^\alpha}+\theta\right)\right)^n\\
=\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)^{-1}\left(1+\frac{x}{\theta n^\alpha }\right)^n,$$

and we see when $\alpha=1$ then this converges to a nondegenerate CDF of

$$F(x)=e^{x/\theta-1}$$

on the support $(-\infty,\theta],$ which is not normal.

---

If the aim is to just assess whether we have asymptotic normality, we can determine this up front just by looking at the support. Since $X_{(n)}\in [0,\theta]$,

$$T_n=n^\alpha \left(\frac{n+1}{n}X_{(n)}-\theta \right)\in \left[-\theta n^\alpha,\frac{1}{n^{1-\alpha}}\theta\right],$$

so that $T_n$ cannot be asymptotically normal for $\alpha\leq 1$.

Comment: I didn't know of $n^\alpha$-consistency. Where can I read about it more?

Comment: I don't have any source on the top of my head, but if you google "root n consistency" (this is what the ordinary CLT gives us), you should find something. e.g. here is something that just came up when I googled it: https://statisticaloddsandends.wordpress.com/2019/06/14/consistency-and-root-n-consistency/

Comment: +1 for your first part: the distribution heads towards a reversed shifted exponential distribution - see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/549408/mle-and-non-normality for something similar.

Comment: @Henry Oh, good to know!

Comment: So in the second part you're using fact that support for standard normal distribution is $(-\infty, \infty)$?

Comment: @taciturno correct

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your approach to this problem is flawed. To check if a sequence $Y_1,Y_2,\dots,$ of variables is asymptotically normal, you need to show that $$\frac{Y_n-E[Y_n]}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(Y_n)}}\to N(0,1).$$ In your case, $Y_n=\frac{n+1}{n}X_{(n)}$, and $E[Y_n]=\theta$. Since you are multiplying $(Y_n-E[Y_n])$  by $\sqrt{n}$, you seem to be assuming that $\text{Var}(Y_n)\sim 1/n$, but you have not proved this. As a first step, you should compute $\text{Var}(\frac{n+1}{n}X_{(n)})$, and then plug that into the expression above and try to work out what the limit is.

To compute $\text{Var}(\frac{n+1}{n} X_{(n)})$, we first find
$$
E[X_{(n)}^2]=\int_0^\theta 2t P(X_{(n)}>t)\,dt=\int_0^\theta 2t(1-(t/\theta)^n)=\theta^2\left(1-\frac{2}{n+2}\right)
$$
which further implies
$$
\text{Var}(X_{(n)})=E[X_{(n)}^2]-E[X_{(n)}]^2=\theta^2(1-\tfrac2{n+2})-\theta^2(1-\tfrac1{n+1})^2=\frac{\theta^2\cdot n}{(n+1)^2(n+2)}
$$
and finally that $\text{Var}(\frac{n+1}nX_{(n)})=\frac{\theta^2}{n(n+2)}$. The important thing is that the variance goes to zero at a rate of $1/n^2$, or that the standard deviation decreases like $1/n$, so you need to multiply by $n$ to compensate so that a nontrivial limiting distribution exists. Therefore, we need to look at
$$
P\left(n\cdot\left(\frac{n+1}nX_{(n)}-\theta\right)\le t\right),
$$
and see if the limit is equal to $P(W\le t)$ for some normal variable $W$. But now we have reduced the problem to Golden_Ratio's answer with $\alpha=1$. Computing the same limit they did, we see
$$
P\left(n\cdot\left(\frac{n+1}nX_{(n)}-\theta\right)\le t\right)=\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)^{-1}\left(1+\frac{t}{\theta n}\right)^n \longrightarrow e^{t/\theta-1}
$$
Since $e^{t/\theta-1}$ is *not* the distribution of a normal variable, we conclude that the estimator is not asymptotically normal. Instead, the distribution approaches $1-Z$, where $Z$ is exponential with parameter $\theta$ (or $1/\theta$, I can never remember which is which).

Comment: Did you read my question? I don't need to check if **sequence** is asymptotically normal. I need to check if **estimator** is asymptotically normal. Also you could check theorem statement, for example here: https://www.statisticshowto.com/asymptotic-normality/. It says I **need** multiply by $\sqrt{n}$

Comment: @taciturno I did read your question completely, and I promise that my answer is relevant. You do not just have one estimator, you have a sequence of estimators, one for each $n$. Each of those estimators is a statistic, and is therefore a random variable, hence a sequence of random variables.

Comment: @taciturno Also, that source you linked is just wrong. It is true that _most of the time_ when checking asymptotic normality, you multiply by $\sqrt{n}$. For example, when estimating the sample mean, the variance of the estimator $\hat X_n:=(X_1+\dots+X_n)/n$ grows like $1/\sqrt{n}$, so you need to multiply by $\sqrt{n}$ to compensate. But for the problem at hand, it turns out the variance of $X_{(n)}$ (which is a much different statistic then the sample mean) shrinks must faster, at $O(1/n)$, so you must multiply by $n$.

Comment: @taciturno If you do not believe me, I strongly suggest you ask a math authority figure you trust, like a teacher. They will confirm what I am saying.

Comment: I want to believe you, but the problem is, that this statement (with multiplying by $\sqrt{n}$) was given to me by my prof. and then I just found this first link in google. Can you give me some links proving your point?

Comment: @taciturno See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_distribution#Definition. Note that their definition is more general then mine; they say that a sequence $Z_1,Z_2,\dots$ has an asymptotic distribution if there exist two sequences of constants $(a_n)_{n\ge 1}$ and $(b_n)_{n\ge 1}$ such that $(Z_n-a_n)/b_n$ converges to some nontrivial distribution. In practice, you usually choose $a_n=E[Z_n]$ and $b_n=\sqrt{\text{Var}(Z_n)}$. But either way, it is not necessarily the case that $b_n=1/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: well, ok, I've calculated and $Var(Y_n) =\frac{ \theta^2}{n(n+2)}$. So it turns out that I need to multiply by $\sqrt{n}$ to show asymp. normality? And for the rest of the problem I need only to use central limit theorem for $Y_1, ..., Y_n$?

Comment: @taciturno See edits.